# "Bootstrap could not be loaded" when deploying to Windows CE 7

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-embedded-compact

I am trying to debug a c# application on a Motorola WT41N0 which runs Windows Compact Embedded 7 from Visual Studio 2008. When I press F5 to run the program, once visual studio tries to deploy to the device I get the following error: "The bootstrap could not be loaded."

I have previously run the program successfully on a Motorola WT4090 which runs Windows CE 5.
Does anyone know how I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you installed the Motorola driver for the new device?  I had the same issue until I installed 41x0c70BenPS010007.exe, which is their devices platform SDK.  This will install a new device in Visual Studio.

In the Visual Studio menu go to Tools->Options->Devices Tools->Devices and you should now have a WT41N0c70PSDK ARM7 Device.  If you don't have that then I don't think you can get the boot strap to load.

I did not have to set it as the default VS device or anything it just needs to be there and VS will figure out the rest.

Follow up for Question

From this link: https://support.symbol.com/support/supportcentral/supportcentral.do?id=m1

Click login,  it is on the right hand side (You have to have an account or create an account to download it)
On the next screen after login set the filter for: Product Line:Mobile Computers, Product:WT41N0, Document Type:Software Downloads, then hit “GO”.  The first result should be the “OS Updated Image and the PSDK.”  Follow the link to download it and then finally click “Request Download” near the bottom of the page.  They want a serial number of a device to continue.

You will want to read this before you go any further also.
https://docs.symbol.com/ReleaseNotes/PSDK_for_WT41N0_Readme_1_0_0.htm#Components

Comment: Where can I get 41x0c70BenPS010007.exe from. I have installed the Windows Embedded Compact 7 package builder which has fixed the problem for me, however it is only a 180 day trial so another solution would be good.

Comment: I updated the original answer with details on how you can download the PSDK from Motorola, there was not enough room to put it in a comment.

Comment: I had the same issue on a different device model.  Installing the correct PSDK resolved the issue for me also.

Comment: Worked with following: SDK for Windows CE 7.0
https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/software/developer-tools/mc32n0-platform-sdk.html